# If the mysql result value is an array and generic T is not an array, can it be removed in typescript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, mysql2

```
type User = {
  name: string
  email: string
}
```

This is my code,

```
import type { PoolConnection, RowDataPacket, OkPacket } from "mysql2/promise";

type dbDefaults = RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[];
type dbQuery<T> = T & dbDefaults;

type FlattenIfArray<T> = T extends (infer R)[] ? R : T;

function isFlattenArray<T>(rows: any[]): rows is T[] {
  return rows.length < 1;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
export async function queryWrapper<T>(
  { query, values }: { query: string; values?: string[] },
  conn: PoolConnection
): Promise<T | undefined> {
  try {
    await conn.beginTransaction();
    const [rows, _] = await conn.query<dbQuery<T>>(query, values || undefined);
    await conn.commit();

    if (isFlattenArray<FlattenIfArray<T>>(rows)) {
      return rows;
    }

    return rows;
  } catch (error) {
    await conn.rollback();
  } finally {
    conn.release();
  }
}
```

Mysql code only returns the array

There is no problem with `User[]`.
But When using `User`, I want to remove the arrangement.

So I used this code, but it didn't work. What should I do?

---

---

I added additional explanation.

`const result = queryWrapper<User>(query, values, conn)`
When use `user`, It comes out like this.

```
[
  {
   name: "user-name",
   email: "user@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

But I want it comes out like this.

```
{
 name: "user-name",
 email: "user@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mbAKBN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  Also, what does "remove the arrangement" mean?  Can you show exactly what happens with `User`? Also, you say "I used this, but it didn't work", what didn't work about it?

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of explanation. ( I'm not good at English )
`remove the arrangement` meant the `flat` function of js.

Comment: I guess this question really is mysql specific and furthermore is a runtime issue; nothing you do with the TypeScript type system will change what data comes out of your function.  Maybe a mysql+TypeScript expert will come along and help you, but my suggestion would be write your runtime code and then use type assertions or `any` to get the types you expect.. like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3533w) maybe? Hard to tell without a [mre].  Strongly typing results of string sql queries isn't something the compiler can do safely, so I doubt you're going to find anything wonderful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll reply by myself.

```
type dbDefaults =
  | RowDataPacket[]
  | RowDataPacket[][]
  | OkPacket
  | OkPacket[]
  | ResultSetHeader;

type Query = { query: string; values?: any[] };

type QueryFunction<T = any> = () => Promise<[T & dbDefaults, FieldPacket[]]>;

type AlwaysArray<T> = T extends (infer R)[] ? R[] : T[];
// eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
export async function queryTransactionWrapper<T = any>(
  queries: QueryFunction[],
  conn: PoolConnection
): Promise<[AlwaysArray<T>, FieldPacket[]][] | undefined> {
  try {
    await conn.beginTransaction();
    // await conn.query("START TRANSACTION;");

    const executedQueries = await Promise.all(
      queries.map((query) => {
        return query();
      })
    );

    // await conn.query("COMMIT;");
    await conn.commit();
    return executedQueries;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(colors.blue(JSON.stringify(error)));
    await conn.rollback();
  } finally {
    conn.release();
  }
}

export function findOne({ query, values }: Query, conn: PoolConnection) {
  return function () {
    return conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>(query, values);
  };
}

export function find({ query, values }: Query, conn: PoolConnection) {
  return function () {
    return conn.query<RowDataPacket[]>(query, values);
  };
}

export function update({ query, values }: Query, conn: PoolConnection) {
  return function () {
    return conn.query<ResultSetHeader>(query, values);
  };
}

export function insert({ query, values }: Query, conn: PoolConnection) {
  return function () {
    return conn.query<OkPacket>(query, values);
  };
}
```

when call findOneUser

```
async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<IUser | undefined> {
    const conn = await this.mysql.getConnection();
    const query = `Select * FROM ${USER_TABLE} WHERE email=?`;

    const findUserQueryFunction = findOne({ query, values: [email] }, conn);

    const executedQueries = await queryTransactionWrapper<IUser>(
      [findUserQueryFunction],
      conn
    );
    if (!executedQueries) {
      throw new Error();
    }
    const [[rows]] = executedQueries;

    return rows[0];
  }
```

if <IUser[]>, `findByEmail` returns rows
else returns rows